# How to get NUNIT and OPENCOVER result without executing the test cases twice on CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, opencover

I have setup CC.NET to run NUNIT first and then OPENCOVER. I have around 2500 NUNIT unit test cases which takes around 2 hours for execution. For OPENCOVER same unit test cases are run by OPENCOVER and entire operation takes close to 5 hours.

Is there any way using which I can run the test cases only once and get the NUNIT as well as OPENCOVER result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, OpenCover launches nunit and profiles it, as such you should be able to tell nunit (via OpenCover) to save results to a file; requiring only one execution?

See the `/xml` switch to [nunit-console.exe](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2)

Then get ccnet to merge in the results from both nunit and OpenCover.